# Find index of dict in array of dict

Tags: ios, swift

Why can't I find the index of a dictionary in an array of dictionaries? I know each dictionary's key-value pair is unordered, but the order of dictionaries *within* the array should be ordered, and I should therefore be able to find the index.

For example:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
var array = [[String:AnyObject]]()

dict["name"] = "John" as? AnyObject
dict["city"] = "New York" as? AnyObject
array.append(dict)

for dict in array {

   if let index = find(array, dict) {

       // do something

   }

}
```

I can't perform the function `find(array, dict)`. `Cannot invoke 'find' with an argument list of type '([([String:AnyObject])]), Dictionary<String,AnyObject>'`

Comment: Can you expand your code a bit? Show the entire function `find(array, item)` and also an example of data stored in the array you are passing to the function.

Comment: `dict["city"] = New York` isn't valid. Is this actual working code?

Comment: Did you update to Swift 2.0? There is no `find` any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

You want to use code like this:

```
if let index = array.indexOf(dict) {
    // do something
}
```

But it won't work. Why? Well, check out the definition of the method:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if
    /// `value` is not found.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
    @warn_unused_result
    public func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}
```

This method will only work if the array's elements are `Equatable`. But `Dictionary`s aren't `Equatable`.

Even if your `find()` method doesn't work exactly this way, it must at some point rely on `Equatable`, which is why your code is failing.

#### Solutions

You could declare a custom struct and use that, which is preferable for a number of reasons:

```
struct Person : Equatable {
    let name : String
    let city : String
}

func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
    return true
}

let john = Person(name: "John", city: "New York")
let jane = Person(name: "Jane", city: "Boston")

var array = [john, jane]

for person in array {
    if let index = array.indexOf(person) {
        // do something with index
    }
}
```

For a quick-and-dirty solution, just call `enumerate()`, which includes the index of each element in a tuple:

```
var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
var array = [[String:AnyObject]]()

dict["name"] = "John"
dict["city"] = "New York"
array.append(dict)

for (index, element) in array.enumerate() {
    // do something with index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Aarons answer (which is great) you could also use the idetity operator:

```
for eachDict in array {
      if eachDict === dict {
           Save the World....
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also do like this:

```
   var arrayOfDic: [[String: String]] = []
   let searchAbleDic:[String: String]
   var row:Int = 0

   for var i = 0; i < self.arrayOfDic.count; i++ 
   {
      let arrayElement:[String: String] = self.arrayOfDic[i]
      if arrayElement.keys.first == searchAbleDic.keys.first
      {
         //Found
      }
   }
```